# How to configure Hibernate to support MySQL JSON_TABLE?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hibernate allow us to define function which it doesn't know about:

```java
registerFunction("GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?1)"));
```

This function can be called directly via `CriteriaBuilder`:

```java
criteriaBuilder.function("GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT", String.class, path);
```

However, I'm not sure how to define a function for `JSON_TABLE` -- specifically, I do not know what the `type` parameter should be. I need to fill in the blank here:

```java
registerFunction("JSON_TABLE", new SQLFunctionTemplate(???, "JSON_TABLE(?1, ?2 COLUMNS (?3))"));
```

I've looked at the implementations for `org.hibernate.Type`, and some stand out but I'm not sure how to use them, or which is the correct type:

- `ArrayType`
- `EntityType` -- which is abstract, but could be one of `OneToManyEntityType` or `OneToOneType` but this doesn't seem correct.

---

My end goal is to be able to build a query with a subquery that uses a JSON table. Here is a simplified example of the SQL I'm trying to re-create via Hibernate.

```sql
SET @q = 'A';

SELECT
    x.id,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(x.properties, 'ALL', 'A', NULL, '$[*].value')),
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(x.properties, 'ALL', 'B', NULL, '$[*].value')),
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(x.properties, 'ALL', 'C', NULL, '$[*].value'))
FROM  JSON_TABLE('
    [
        { 
            "id": "5",
            "properties": [ 
                { "key": "abc", "value": "A" },
                { "key": "abc", "value": "A" }
            ]
        },
        { 
            "id": "6", 
            "properties": [ 
                { "key": "abc", "value": "A" },
                { "key": "abc", "value": "C" }
            ]
        }
    ]', '$[*]' COLUMNS(
    id INT PATH '$.id',
    `key` VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.key', 
    properties JSON PATH '$.properties')) x
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        JSON_TABLE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('[', JSON_SEARCH(x.properties, 'ALL', @q, NULL, '$[*].value'), ']'), '[[', '['), ']]', ']'), '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            `path` VARCHAR(100) PATH '$'
        )) paths
    WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(x.properties, paths.path)) = @q
);
```

Alternatively, if there is a better way to handle a situation where I need to search for one or more JSON properties/values, I'm all ears.

Comment: You may try to parse using scalar functions. See [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fX63PBCU). JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_UNQUOTE and JSON_LENGTH should be easily registered. If the numbers table exists in some service table of your database then `cte1` and recursion is excess. In this case you may avoid CTEs and use subqueries.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite follow.